# Unable to get PhpMailer working with Office 365

Tags: php, office365, phpmailer

I hope the day finds you well.

I'm doing a bit of work on an existing PHP site (it should be noted that I am far from a PHP expert) which has a web form not currently working.  This form simply takes user input, turns it into an email and sends that email to the users office account.  It stopped working when they switched to Office 365 as their email provider.  The form is using the PhpMailer library to handle the sending, so I've modified it to use the Office 365 settings [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/POP-and-IMAP-settings-for-Outlook-Office-365-for-business-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c).  When it sends I'm getting the following error:

```
2017-02-01 21:50:17 Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:2525, 
timeout=10, options=array ( ) 2017-02-01 21:50:28   Connection: Failed to 
connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client() 
[function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to smtp.office365.com:587
(Connection timed out) 2017-02-01 21:50:28  SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to 
server: Connection timed out (110)
Message delivery failed...RFI1
```

This is output directly to the webpage because of the way it's setup.  Here is the PhpMailer settings I've been putting in:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail-> IsSMTP();
$mail->Host       = "smtp.office365.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = 'username';
$mail->Password   = 'pass';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;

$mail->From       = $from;
$mail->Mailer     = "smtp";
$mail->FromName   = 'Generic message';
```

I've looked all over the web to see what I might be doing wrong here.  The ISP hosting the site says that they're not blocking anything, and Microsoft says it's that I don't have SSL configured properly.  Now granted, I'm not an expert in this system, I don't have direct access to the server and the site itself is strangely built and I can't get it to run properly in a local server.  Still, I have a hard time thinking that a connection timeout could be caused by an SSL issue.  Does anyone have any ideas of what else could be causing this problem?

edit: As was pointed out the port in the error message didn't match what was in the code.  I've tried several ports based on what I've read, and grabbed the text from each at different times.

Comment: port 2525  is odd, it does not seem to be using the port you set

Comment: Yeah, that was my bad.  I cut and pasted the code from an earlier time, then tried it with a different port number just to be sure, and grabbed the error from that run.

Comment: from your server run `telnet smtp.office365.com 587` see if you get a connection

Comment: Don't have ssh access to the server.  Kinda working half blind.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't just make up values and hope it works. Office365 config is bog-standard and identical to gmail other than the `Host` value, so base your code on [the gmail example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) provided with PHPMailer.

As for the specific problem you've got here, I suspect it's that `SMTPSecure = 'ssl'` will not work with `Port = 587`; for port 587 (explicit TLS) you need `SMTPSecure = 'tls'`.

Comment: I appreciate the input and I have been using the example to which you linked.  Also I've tried both protocols and still no luck.

Comment: In that case I'd guess that your ISP is blocking outbound SMTP. It's very common. There are some tests you can do in the troubleshooting guide to check for that.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting `tls` instead of `ssl` as encryption layer as was mentioned before, `$mail->From` needs to explicitly specified and it should be identical to `$mail->Username` property.

Here is a *modified* example:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail-> IsSMTP();
$mail->Host       = "smtp.office365.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = "jondoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com";
$mail->Password   = 'P@ssw0rd';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; //TLS
$mail->Port       = 587;

$mail->From       = $mail->Username;  //mandatory and identical to Username property 

$mail->Subject = "Hello message";
$mail->Body = "Body goes here...";
$mail->addAddress('janedoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com');


if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but still no luck.  I'm still getting the same 'Connection timed out' error.